# Children being corrupted will they enter jannat?

Tags: salat, dua, jannah, jahannam

Salaam aliqum. My ex husband has been awarded custody of my son. For what reason i don't know. But the shaytan is living in my sons dad. He is spreading his poison onto my son. I'm sure the devil is starting to take over my son. What should i do as i hardly see my son and unable to pray for him. He was born as a Muslim and first few years i was there trying to protect his soul.
 Will he go to jahanum if the shaytan takes over his body?
 He is only five and innocent but this will affect him in later years as his dad is wicked. And i really mean wicked iblees livs in him and whispers to him but I'm unable to get my son away from him.
 Will i be able to take him to jannat, with my prayers for him, if I'm lucky enough to enter?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that shaytan takes over his body? Is your ex husband a Muslim?

Answer (score 1):

In islam, it is perfectly clear that no human has any way to help any other human with regards to akhirah. Not your mother, not your sister, not your daughter, not a stranger. Muhammad prayed for his uncle and visited him frequently, inviting him to islam, for ten years, and Abu Talib still died a kafir according to most scholars. Ibrahim's father did not listen to him. Nuh's son did not listen to him. What happens to your son is the decision of god alone according to islam, and there is an ayah to that effect saying roughly "whomever god guides, no one can lead astray, and whomever god leads astray, no one can guide". 28:56 even specifically addresses Muhammad, saying that he cannot guide those he loves; perhaps - check tafsir on this - that verse is even in reference to Abu Talib.